# dartEditor file hierarchy and library/part logic

Tags: dart, dart-pub, dart-editor

When I create a 'Web Application' with DartEditor in Windows8, it gives me this hierarchy

```
ClientView/
  packages/
  pubspec.lock
  pubspec.yaml
  web/
    packages/
    clientview.css
    clientview.dart
    clientview.dart.js
    clientview.dart.js.deps
    clientview.dart.js.map
    clientview.html
```

I then add the lib/ file:

```
  web/
    ...
    lib/
      src/
        canvas.dart
        i_drawable.dart
        node.dart
      client_canvas.dart
    ...
```

**client_canvas.dart file**

```dart
library client_view;

import 'dart:html';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart'; 

// Interface
part 'src/i_drawable.dart';

// Class
part 'src/canvas.dart';
part 'src/node.dart';
```

In each of the files included after the 'part' keyword, I've added this line:

```dart
part of client_view;
```

But it seems that none of the classes can be accessed by the other dart code

```dart
class Canvas implements IDrawable // no such type 'IDrawable'
abstract class Node implements IDrawable // no such type 'IDrawable'
class CustomNode extends Node // no such type 'Node' (if try to create a custom node)
```

I guess it's the way pubs and library are organized that I've not understood yet.

So what I tried to do is to create a library, inside the same project, I'd like to import that library inside the clientview.dart file that is called by the clientview.html file.

Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using relative imports, and everything appears to be part of the same library, I see no obvious reason for the errors. Maybe you can share some more details.

You should probably reorganize your source tree to be more inline with Pub standards though. `web/` and `lib/` should both be top level directories, otherwise you won't be able to do `package:` imports of your own libraries. This is one reason why it's recommended that `web/` only contain entry points (scripts with a `main()` method) and everything else should be in `lib/`.

Also, I would try to use `part` very sparingly. I find it much better to define almost every file as a library and just import them. It makes dependencies for each file much more clear and allows consumers to only import the interfaces, and not the implementations. `export` makes it possible to build a library that exposes the definitions of another.

Finally, a style nit: Dart isn't C# and we don't use that ugly 'I' prefix on our interfaces :-) Just name your interface `Drawable`.